# AKKA Typed SLF4J NOP warning

Tags: akka, slf4j, akka-http

I am using AKKA Typed 2.6.5 with AKKA HTTP...

and getting below error

SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.

I have imported every possible sbt repository and tested but still logging is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a dependency to an implementation of the SLF4J API. SLF4J is only an interface, and requires you to provide an implementation of your choice, as described in [the documentation linked from the error message](http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders).

A popular implementation is [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch). You can include it in your project by adding it to your `libraryDependencies`:

```
libraryDependencies += "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.2.3"
```

You can configure it by adding a file at `src/main/resources/logback.xml` with contents like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <file>myapp.log</file>
        <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>myapp_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%date{ISO8601}] [%level] [%logger] [%marker] [%thread] - %msg MDC: {%mdc}%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ASYNC" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.AsyncAppender">
        <queueSize>8192</queueSize>
        <neverBlock>true</neverBlock>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE" />
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="ASYNC"/>
    </root>
</configuration>
```

You can configure this to the needs of your application. See the [Logback manual](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/) for details on configuration. Be sure to use an async appender as demonstrated above, so that logging doesn't result in blocking I/O on your Akka dispatcher threads.

There is more information in the Akka documentation at https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/logging.html#slf4j-backend

Comment: Thanks very much the solution worked .
I was using sbt and the maven site had %Test appended to all dependencies, once i removed the %Test in my build file the logger started working.